# How to use NSString's writeToFile method

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to write an Objective-C program which writes all [knownTimeZoneNames](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nstimezone/1856138-knowntimezonenames?language=objc) to a file. So far I've tried:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(void) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:@"knownTimeZoneNames.txt" contents:nil attributes:nil];


    for (NSString *name in [NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames]) {
        [name writeToFile:"knownTimeZoneNames.txt" atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
//      NSLog(@"The time zone is %@", name);

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that if I comment in the line with `NSLog` and comment out the one with `writeToFile`, the program prints the expected output. As it is, however, I get warnings about incompatible pointer types:

```
write_known_timezone_names.m: In function ‘main’:
write_known_timezone_names.m:10:3: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
   [name writeToFile:"knownTimeZoneNames.txt" atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
   ^
write_known_timezone_names.m:10:3: note: expected ‘struct NSString *’ but argument is of type ‘char *’
write_known_timezone_names.m:10:3: warning: passing argument 4 of ‘writeToFile:atomically:encoding:error:’ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
write_known_timezone_names.m:10:3: note: expected ‘struct NSError **’ but argument is of type ‘id’
The file write_known_timezone_names.m has been compiled and can be run using the command ./write_known_timezone_names.
```

and if I try to run the program I get a `Segmentation fault`:

```
2017-02-03 12:31:49.485 write_known_timezone_names[23626] autorelease called without pool for object (0x17d6f90) of class NSDataStatic in thread <NSThread: 0x175e330>
2017-02-03 12:31:49.487 write_known_timezone_names[23626] autorelease called without pool for object (0x18e4f70) of class NSMutableDataMalloc in thread <NSThread: 0x175e330>
2017-02-03 12:31:49.489 write_known_timezone_names[23626] autorelease called without pool for object (0x18ec110) of class NSDataMalloc in thread <NSThread: 0x175e330>
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

How can I fix this program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int main(void) {
 [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:@"knownTimeZoneNames.txt" contents:nil attributes:nil];

NSMutableString *timeZones = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
for (NSString *name in [NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames]) {
    [timeZones appendFormat:@"%@\n", name];    
}
[timeZones writeToFile:@"knownTimeZoneNames.txt" atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You missed @ before filename.
Correct code:

```
int main(void) {
 [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:@"knownTimeZoneNames.txt" contents:nil attributes:nil];


for (NSString *name in [NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames]) {
    [name writeToFile:@"knownTimeZoneNames.txt" atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    //      NSLog(@"The time zone is %@", name);

}
return 0;}
```

Comment: It seems the program keeps on overwriting the time zone on the first line and I only see a single line with the last time zone in the end. Any idea on how to write each time zone to a new line?

Answer (score 2):

1. Regarding `Segmentation fault`: As the error message *autorelease called without pool* reveals you have to wrap the code in an autorelease pool

   ```
   @autoreleasepool {

       [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:@"knownTimeZoneNames.txt" contents:nil attributes:nil];

       for (NSString *name in [NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames]) {
           [name writeToFile:@"knownTimeZoneNames.txt" atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
           //NSLog(@"The time zone is %@", name);
       }
       return 0;
   }
   ```
2. <strike>I don't know where you want to write the file but a path must start with a slash and in iOS you have to get programmatically one of the directories you have permission to write into.</strike>
3. And even if the other issues are resolved your resulting text file will contain just **one** line (the name of the last iteration). To get all names – one per line – use this instead of the repeat loop

   ```
   NSArray *nameArray = [NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames];
   NSString *names = [nameArray componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
   ```

Comment: I'm actually running this code not on iOS, but in Linux using GNUstep through the following command: `gcc $filename \`gnustep-config --objc-flags\` -lobjc -lgnustep-base -o $runfile`, where `$filename` is the .m file and `$runfile` the output file to run.

Comment: Why do you confuse the people by the `ios` tag??

Comment: Sorry about that, I removed it.

Answer (score 1):

Please, try this

```
for (NSString *name in [NSTimeZone knownTimeZoneNames]) {
     // You was trying to pass chars, but you have to pass string.   
    [name writeToFile:@"knownTimeZoneNames.txt" atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    //      NSLog(@"The time zone is %@", name);
}
```